# How does the function argument of the tibble() operate in relation to the vector in the first argument?

Tags: r

I am teaching myself some R and starting from the very beginning. Currently working on how to build tibbles, as I read that they are "modernized" versions of data frames. I am trying to build a tibble which will operate on a vector, but am confused on the result. This is the code that I am using:

[image: Code that I am using to format my tibble]

As I understand from my reading, the mean, median, and sd would be calculated for the vector in the first argument, c(1,2,3). But that is so, for example, the mean of that vector should be 2, but that is not the result that I am getting. For the mean I get 1, for the median I get 2, and for the sd I get 3. I'm almost sure that I'm typing in the right code, but I have misunderstood how that code is supposed to be run. Is tibble() calculating the mean of 1, the median of 2, and the sd of 3? That also does not make sense to me. I am looking for some clarification on how to read this very basic piece of code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP created a function column instead of applying the function, it would be

```
tibble(id = 1:3, output = c(mean(id), median(id), sd(id)))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#    id output       
#  <int>  <dbl>
#1     1      2
#2     2      2
#3     3      1
```

instead of

```
tibble(id = 1:3, func = c(mean, median, sd))
```